# Is is possible to have a collection of generic collections?

Tags: java

I'm writing some code that needs to process an arbitrary number of lists of doubles. However, although I can declare function parameters of type `List<List<Double>>` I'm having trouble creating actual instances since I need to create instances of a concrete class such as `ArrayList`

I've tried

```
List<? extends List<Double>> inputs = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
inputs.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

and

```
List<? extends List<? extends Double>> inputs = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
inputs.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

but in both cases I get a compile error on the call to `add()` saying that the method is not applicable for arguments of type `ArrayList<Double>`

This works

```
List<List<Double>> inputs = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
inputs.add((List<Double>) new ArrayList<Double>());
```

but it's kind of ugly to have to use casts in this way. Is there a better approach?

Comment: You don't usually need to get involved with generic wildcards (? etc.) in Java, unless you're creating an API or doing something else advanced. Certainly not for standard uses of collections. The sample chapter here is good http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can omit the cast since this one is perfectly valid. Each ArrayList is a List.

```
List<List<Double>> inputs = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
inputs.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Comment: You're right it does - I was sure I got an error when I tried this though, obviously I got confused :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding what the wildcard means. `<? extends List>` does not mean "anything that extends list" it means "Some specific thing that extends list, but we don't know what it is."  So it's illegal to add an ArrayList to that, because we don't know if ArrayList is the specific thing that's in this collection.

Just plain old :

```
  List<List<Double>> list = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
  list.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

works fine

Comment: Thanks. I was obviously confusing myself yesterday. I was so sure that the simple case wouldn't work that I started with the wildcard approach.

Answer (score 0):

Two very different situations when deciding what kind of type should be declared:

1) in a public interface. use proper abstract type.

```
    public List<List<Double>> querySomething();
```

2) as an implementation detail. use concrete type

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
```

I'm guessing you are on the 2nd case.

Comment: Yes and no. I wanted to construct an interface that would accept a `List<List<Double>>` and was writing some test code to exercise the interface. Thanks for your help.